# Create string from only part of user input

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

The project I am working on now is an interactive one. It is focused on learning language. I want the user to be able to input data, and the console to respond with a set sentence based on what the user wrote.

I am stuck at "My name is". I have been researching the `scanner.skip` function all morning, but cannot seem to find the information I need on how to get it to do what I want it to do. I want the user to write "My name is [name]." I then want the console to split this answer into two separate strings, "My name is" and "[name]".

I want to be able to check that "My name is" matches exactly to "My name is", while ignoring whatever "[name]" happens to be. I want to be able to access "[name]" later on, however, so that the console is able to talk to the user using their entered name. How would I go about doing this with the `scanner.skip` function? Is this even the correct function to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I'd use substring:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();
        System.out.printf("line: '%s'%n", line);
        if (line.startsWith("My name is ")) {
            String name = line.substring("My name is ".length());
            System.out.printf("name: '%s'%n", name);
        } else {
            // print error or something
            System.out.println("Error: line has to start with 'My name is ' string.");
        }
    }
}
```

BufferedReader is used, because it's quicker and in this case it's not important for later processing...

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/G2jrDG)

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot.
I have tried using the BufferedReader function after the error message to prompt the user to retry the entry, but continue to get errors saying that the variable has already been defined earlier in the code. I'm afraid I will be using too many loops and repeating code if I continue to make new inputs for each new try. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String var = "My Name Is Uly";
        String name = var.replace("My Name Is ", "");
        String firsPart = var.replace(" " + name, "");

        System.out.println(firsPart + " " + name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to provide the introductory text (" My name is :") then you can get the name like this:

```
cn = System.console();
name = cn.readLine("My name is  ");
System.out.println("Name entered : " + name);
```

alternatively you can also parse the string:

```
cn = System.console();
name = cn.readLine();
//n= no of chars in your text :My name is 
name = name.substring(n);

System.out.println("Name entered : " + name );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `skip`. Just read the whole strong, the using functions available as members of the `String` class, check that it starts with "My name is", and, if it does, take a substring starting and the end of that prefix (+1 for space), and store it in a vvariable to use as the name later.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc;
    do {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Bye");
            break;
        }else if(s.length()>11 && s.substring(0,10).equalsIgnoreCase("my name is")) {
            String name = s.substring(11);
            System.out.println("your name is:"+name);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry incorrect answer ... ");
        }
    }while (true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name{
    public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str = input.nextLine(); 

    if(str.indexOf("My name is ") >= 0){
       String name = str.substring(str.indexOf("My name is ")+11, str.length());

       System.out.println("Your name is: "+name);
    }
    else
       System.out.println("Error: Could not find name!");

    }
}
```

Tests if the entered String has an index of "My name is " and then breaks the String into a substring to extract the name from the input.